# Xcode The repository "(null)" could not be reached

Tags: xcode, git, repository

Xcode git problems again.  Now when I routinely create new projects (inside of or outside of a workspace) I can't seem to get Source Control operations to work.  However, I can see the repository in the Organizer and I can use external tools, including git command line tools with no problem.  When I try anything via the File->Source Control menu I just see...

The repository "(null)" could not be reached

I've seen other people report this for SVN, which I don't use for these projects.  Any advice?

Thanks,
~chuck

Comment: Is it for XCode4.5 like in https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4069380?start=0&tstart=0 ? And would simply restarting XCode would make the issue go away?

Comment: This is Xcode 4.4.1.  Restarting XCode alone didn't fix anything.  Some random combination of things I tried at different times (e.g. deleting derived data, and File->Source Control->Refresh Status after commit -a and push from the command line) seemed to cure broken projects.  Now new projects seem to be ok but I expect it to break again.  I've stopped using workspaces since it seems to really break a lot of stuff.

Comment: Ok, interesting, even that that doesn't exactly inspire confidence ;)

Answer (score 0):

If your project is located in, let's say `/usr/local/projects/your_project`, then *Xcode* has a problem with locating the .git repository and the git functionality within *Xcode* does not work with that project.

Instead, just store your projects in `~/Documents/projects/your_project` and *Xcode*'s git functionality should start working again.